# Is there a way to write raw audio data to Pulse Audio from Java?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I am writing an audio application, and testing on Ubuntu 22.04.

I am using javax.sound.sampled sampled library.

I get available mixer info as follows...

```
    Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++)
        Log.i("["+i+"]"+" "+mixers[i].getDescription());

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
```

This list all my hardware audio devices available to me. When I then subsequently try to open and use that audio hardware...

```
    mLine = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(mAudioFormat, mMixerInfo);
    int bufferSizeInBytes = mBufferSizeInFrames * mChannels * mBytesPerSmp;
    mLine.open(mAudioFormat, bufferSizeInBytes);
```

It will only succeed if there is no other application currently playing audio on that device (like my browser, or a game).

Is there a way I can write raw audio not directly to a hardware device, but to a higher level software mixer like ALSA or Pulse (which I assume all my other applications do)?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using Java 11.

Comment: When you say “It will only succeed,” how do you know the sound output is not succeeding?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yes correct, I am getting an exception. I will update the question with that missing info.